# How to Connect Apache Flink with IBM MQ? Missing Connector or Configuration Issue?

Tags: java, apache-flink, ibm-mq, flink-streaming

I'm in the process of modernizing an existing application that uses `Spring Boot`. The application's behavior is straightforward: it retrieves large messages from an `IBM MQ` server, performs some validation/processing, and then creates or updates records in a database.

The challenge is that I'm locked into using `IBM MQ` and the existing database technology due to the constraints of the project.

I'm considering the use of `Apache Flink` for this task, as I've successfully employed it in similar workflows before. However, I'm facing a roadblock: I can't seem to find a suitable connector for `IBM MQ` within the `Apache Flink` ecosystem.

For the sink, I was thinking the `JDBC` connector should work because I see it [provides support](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/jdbc/) for `Oracle`.

Has anyone successfully integrated `Apache Flink` with `IBM MQ`? If so, which connector did you use, or do you have any other suggestions or insights to share regarding this integration?

Comment: That's pretty much as basic as you can get. Pull a message, process it then create/update a database record. Why use Apache Flink? Seems like overkill to me. All you need are the Oracle & MQ JAR files and then you write some Java code to do the work.

Comment: It's "encoded" in the _modernizing_ part. There are problems with the number of pods, expected throughput, and because the database is shared these processes get out of sync frequently when the same it's not available. It's not an optimal environment, but automatic backpressure handling, resource management, and stateful processing are the main factors. I oversimplified the question, but the processing is not that simple; it requires to maintain (and update) some state information — this is a winner because it's built-in feature in `Apache Flink`.

Comment: There is no IBM MQ connector for Flink